# How do I make Selenium webdriver to wait for an element to change its attribute to something else in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Below is my element;

```
String sId = driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).getAttribute("data-id");
```

Since now the attribute value is stored in "sId", I now need to tell Selenium to wait until data-id attribute value is **NOT equal** to sID.
I have tried the code below with no luck:

```
wait.until_not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.xpath(path), sId));
```

I get the error:

> The method until_not(ExpectedCondition) is undefined for the
>   type WebDriverWait

Also even if I change "until_not" to "until" I get this warning:

> The method textToBePresentInElement(By, String) from the type
>   ExpectedConditions is deprecated

How do I do it?

Comment: To wait until **data-id** _attribute_ `value is NOT equal to sID` will be False-Possitive. IMO, if _usecase_ permits,  you should wait for `value is equal to sID`

Answer (score 2):

If you are checking the attribute value checking the text won't help you, those are two different things.

You can combine the `not` and `attributeToBe` [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for that

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(By.xpath(path), "data-id", sId)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use not from Expected conditions, for example:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(<element>, <elementtext>)));
```

Or you can also use expected conditions invisibility method:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(locator, text));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow code

```
String sId = driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).getAttribute("data-id");        

boolean expectedCondition = false;
boolean timeOut = false;
int second = 1;
do {
    try {
        //timeout for 60 seconds
        if(second>60) {
            timeOut = true;
        }
        String expectedId = driver.findElement(By.xpath(path)).getAttribute("data-id");
        if(! expectedId.equals(sId)) {
            expectedCondition=true;
        }else {
            second++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        second++;
    }
}while(expectedCondition==false && timeOut==false);
```